# How to request, store, and use an access token in Meteor while using the Instagram API

Tags: javascript, api, meteor, instagram

How does one request, store, and use an access token from an API in the Meteor framework?  I am currently trying to make requests from the (Instagram API)[https://instagram.com/developer/authentication/], but I first need to request an access token and store it for later use.

What is the general structure for doing this?  I have my Client Id and Client Secret stored in the settings.json and have the services configuration package loaded.  I think I need to create some sort of Method using http.get, but if someone could give a brief walkthrough that would be greatly appreciated ! Not much on this in the Meteor Docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Bozhao](https://atmospherejs.com/bozhao/accounts-instagram) Package for this.

Just install it.

```
meteor add bozhao:accounts-instagram
```

And this will work exactly like tha core accounts - facebook || google || twitter

and you can do something like this on the [accountsOnCreateUser](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_oncreateuser) Methods

```
if (user.services.instagram) {
    console.log("-- REGISTED USER WITH INSTAGRAM ");
    instagramProfile = {
      socialProfileUrl: user.services.instagram.profile_picture,
      socialName: user.services.instagram.full_name,
      service: "Instagram",
      profileUrl: "https://instagram.com/"+ user.services.instagram.username
    };
user.profile = instagramProfile;
}
```

Now knowing this, you can see that we have the user data inside the `user.services.instagram` object, there should be a accessToken and id field that you make POST / GET http request to the `https://instagram.com/api/v1/`.

I have never done a HTTP request to the Instagram API but it should be similar to facebook (if not sorry the below code dosnt help you to much).

Simple http call using the params.

```
Meteor.http.get("https://instagram.com/api/v1/", {
      headers: {
        "User-Agent": "Meteor/1.0"
      },
      params: {
        access_token: user.services.accessToken
      }
    },function(error,result){
      if(!error){
        console.log(result);
      }
    });
```